# Temporary images with Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

Is there a way to make a temporary "image" with Pyglet? (Something akin to LÖVE's [Canvas](https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas)).

Basically, I want to have an object that I could blit stuff like sprites and text to, and then blit this temporary image to the window.

I tried creating an image with [`pyglet.image.create()`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/image/pyglet.image.create.html#pyglet.image.create), but apparently it procures an `ImageData` which you can't blit to.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Is the important part being able to draw without an associated window (off screen)?

Comment: Basically, yeah. I want to draw off screen and then render part of the image on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [AbstractImage](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/image/pyglet.image.AbstractImage.html). It has all the methods I think you want - creating an image offline, `blitting` stuff to it:

```
myimage.blit_into('sprite1',x,y,z)
myimage.blit_into('sprite2',x+20,y,z)
```

and then blitting it to the active frame:

```
myimage.blit(x,y[,z])
```

etc.

Comment: `pyglet.image.ImageException: Cannot blit images onto <AbstractImage 640x128>.`

Comment: I'll need more info. Also, did you read the docs? are you constructing the proper abstract image? it has a few sub-classes (Texture etc)

Comment: I have. I've linked to the documentation in my question.
I've also skimmed the source code. The `AbstractImage` thing is complicated. It has the `blit_into` method but by default it throws an error.

Comment: I've tried using `Texture` before, and you can blit `ImageData` into it, but I can't find how to blit the text.

Comment: I checked the source code, the base class doesn't have the method implemented (thus the exception). I'll give it another go later today -but the answer maybe you need an outside library.

Comment: @art-solopov How are you blitting the text? Are you using `text.Label`?

Comment: Yeah, with `text.Label`.

Comment: @art-solopov Sorry it took a while - the `pyglet` code is still a bit incomplete. I don't see any easy way  to get text working yet with pylget except creating an image with the text yourself and blitting that (you can post on github if you want the author's to work on it), though I didn't check the latest code. Otherwise you can try switching frameworks if you don't want to deal with this (pygame, which are the guys working on pyglet maybe?).

Comment: TBH I probably will switch frameworks. Either go with PyGame or try to look into an HTML5/ES6+ framework.
Thank you for your answer regardless!..

Comment: Yup, glad to help (as much as I could anyway)